# How should I include Jquery functions into a project?

Tags: jquery, html

Currently I have several `Jquery` functions in script tags just above my page footer.

```
<script>
    //several Jquery functions in here..
</script>
        <footer>
                <p>Copyright &copy</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the common practice for including `Jquery` functions into a project?

Should I put them into another folder/file and include them in my header?

Comment: Uhm ... you just include them via `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`, that's all you do. jQuery is clientside, while php is serverside. So there is nothing to take care of.

Comment: Yes, I know how one is server side, and other client side. I am just curious the proper way of including several jquery functions into a project. So in your quick example, you're saying I should put them all into a file `jquery.js` and then include them within a script tag, would that script tag be in my `html` header?

Comment: Try to put all these jquery function in a common file and then put it in your project and then call it as in normal HTML file we are calling script. which is <script src = "your script path"></script>. but if you want to include in php file then on very upside of that file, write include_one('js file path')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally where you put your javascript includes is up to you but the bulk of includes usually go before the closing body tag (because it helps the page to load faster). However it is common with sites built on wordpress and other platforms that you see a lot of JS includes at the top.

It all depends on how you design your web system.

Now... the problem you might find if your functions are in the footer is that if you try to call them before they've been defined, then the JS will throw an error. So ideally you don't want to use things like `<a id="btn" onclick="foo()">` within your HTML but instead have this in JS:

```
$('a#btn').click(foo);
```

For basic sites you can probably get away with a single script file.

```
        <script src="/js/jquery.x.x.min.js"></script> <!-- jquery lib -->
        <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>        <!-- your custom scripts -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**Separation of Concerns**

It's deemed best practice to keep your code separated where possible. So all JavaScript code should be in `.js` files, much like how inline CSS is frowned upon and should be in `.css` files. This keeps your code clean and easier to manage.

Comment: Sorry I fixed my question to a little more clear to what I was asking. However you have answered my questions. Thanks!